# nginx RD Gateway on different hostname

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have an HTTP website (publicly accessible) on a specific domain name on port 80. I would like to publicly access RDP via an nginx RD gateway on port 443.

I've searched around on the internet but I'm new to this and I don't really know what I'm looking for.

The HTTP website is running on a separate Ubuntu 17.04 machine, hooked up to my Windows machine running RDP via Ethernet.

Edit: RDP is running on the default RDP port: 3389

Comment: I'm not sure that I would use nginx to proxy traffic like RDP.  You might want to look into haproxy.

Comment: Can I make it play ball with nginx under these circumstances? @Jenos

Comment: You can configure haproxy to listen on any available port.  As long as you don't have nginx listening on 443, you can use that for the RDP proxy.

Comment: I do but on another subdomain... @Jenos

Comment: You won't be able to use either haproxy or nginx in that case.  Nginx's stream proxying (for non-web tcp traffic) binds to the port entirely and isn't able to interpret location blocks.  There's no HTTP headers for it to parse in those cases.  You will most likely want to use a different port.

Comment: D'accord, merci @Jenos